# In how many ways can you choose cleaning managers when person A refuses to clean together with B

Tags: combinatorics

A group of 8 people meet every week and bake together. Three people are responsible for cleaning each time. In how many ways can you choose cleaning managers when person A refuses to clean together with B, and person C offers to clean on the condition that neither A nor B helps.

I have thought that since person A can't work wtih either A or C, they can work in 1*5*4 = 20
different groups but then I realized that I can apply this to both C and B because A, B and C will never work together.

But I'm not sure if it's correct because then there were only be 3 * 20 = 60 ways

Comment: You say $1\cdot 5\cdot 4$... you seem to be saying that order within the group mattered when it does not.  What would the difference be between the groups $A,D,E$ and $A,E,D$?  You also forgot the case where none of $A,B,C$ work.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the last case. But I thought that the answer to the other cases in total should be 5 over 3 and then 4 over 2 and 3 over 1 because when you choose someone you have one less than before you can choose the same person twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break into cases:

- $A$ works (*And so $B$ doesn't and $C$ doesn't*)
- $B$ works (*And so $A$ doesn't and $C$ doesn't*)
- $C$ works (*and so $A$ doesn't and $B$ doesn't*)
- None of $A,B,$ nor $C$ work.

> $3\cdot \binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{3} = 3\cdot 10 + 10 = 40$

Comment: Why not 5 over 3, 4 over 2 and 3 over 1? Also why do you multiply 3 with 5 over 2?

Comment: And how d you calculate the last case?

Comment: In the first case where you do have A and not B and not C, you still need to pick two from the remaining five (D,E,F,G,H).  In the second case where you have B but not A and not C, you again need to pick **two** from the remaining **five**.  Same for thr third case.  The amount needing to be chosen and the amount of options is the same for all the first three cases, hence the multiplication by three.  As for the fourth case... we choose **three** of the five others for our team

Comment: Thanks I get it now.